# How to add graphical elements to each frame of a Video in Real Time?

Tags: matlab, video, real-time, matlab-cvst

So I have a live video feed running in Matlab that analyzes each frame of the video. A moving object is tracked per frame and the 2d coordinates of each frame is individually saved to a 2x1 matrix that is overwritten for each frame. What I would like is to edit the live video feed in realtime, so the coordinates of frame i are represented in the video feed using one of Matlab's graphical elements ('+','o','x' etc). This will be imposed in the video before frame i+1 is processed. Ideally an object will be tracked and in real time, the trajectory will be displayed in the video. Is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
while 1
frame = readFrame(); %% step(vidDevice)
detectedLocation = detectObject(frame); %% 2x1 Matrix, X and Y coordinate of object
%%Impose the detectedLocation in the video feed in real time
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Used insertObjectAnnotation. Only thing I would like is for it not to have a circle or rectangle but rather just a '+' but it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertMarker` to draw a '+', and `insertText` to draw your own text label. There is also `insertShape` for drawing rectangles, circles, or polygons without any text.